# OSError: [WinError 193] when trying to import sklearn in spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder, oserror

I was previously using pyscripter for machine learning purposes and I recently switched to spyder. Unfortunately when I try to import the sklearn module, I'm getting this error traceback :

*File "F:\2. Private\Personnal Improvement\Code\Python\Machine learning\Neural Networks\digitis_selected prediction.py", line 16, in 
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits*

*File "C:\Users\32491\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn_*init*_.py", line 80, in 
from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401*

*File "C:\Users\32491\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn_distributor_init.py", line 22, in 
WinDLL(op.abspath(vcomp140_dll_filename))*

*File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64_*init*_.py", line 364, in **init**
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**

I've read several posts on stack about similar problems with spyder and sklearn. I've tried to install the last version of sklearn (success) update all sub-packages (success) to specify the python.exe path to spyder but none of them are producing any difference. I'm still stuck with this problem that doesn't appear on my other IDE when I try to run my scripts on them...